# Hexagon grid in random shape

Tags: html, css, hexagonal-tiles

I am trying to create a hexagon grid in a random generated shape with max 12 hexagons a row.

The original design of what I am trying to achieve:
[Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9Bw1.jpg)

In this JS Fiddle you can see what I've got so far, but I can't seem to figure out how to add more hexagons to a row, and how to generate a grid like the design.

https://jsfiddle.net/marijnroukens/a4xvLeon/1/

```
hex:nth-child
```

It has something to do with all of the hex:nth-child's.

Thanks in advance for helping me!

Comment: The plugin for the grid I used can be found here: https://github.com/web-tiki/responsive-grid-of-hexagons